# Gauss-Jordan elimination problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Use Gauss-Jordan elimination to solve the linear system:

$3x + 11y +19 = -2\\ 7x +23y +39z = 10\\ -4x -3y -2z = 6$

These are my calculations so far:

Augmented Matrix

$\begin{matrix}3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 11 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 19 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ -2 \\
7 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 23 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 39 \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ 10 \\
-4 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -3\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  -2 \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ 6\end{matrix}$

$\frac{1}{3}R_1 = R_1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ R_2 - 7R_1 = R_2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ R_3 + 4R1 = R_3$

$\begin{matrix} 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{11}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{19}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{2}{3} \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{8}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{16}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ \frac{44}{3} \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{35}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{70}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{10}{3}\end{matrix}$

$-\frac{3}{8}R_2 = R_2 \ \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ \ \frac{3}{35}R_3 = R_3$

$\begin{matrix}1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{11}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{19}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{2}{3} \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{11}{2} \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ \frac{2}{7} \end{matrix}$

$R_3 - R_2 = R_3$

$\begin{matrix}1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{11}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{19}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{2}{3} \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{11}{2} \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \ \ \ \ \ -
 \frac{73}{14}\end{matrix}$

The last row in this matrix means that $0x + 0y + 0z = -\frac{73}{14}$. This is not possible so the system is inconsistent, with no solution. But this is made evident before even completing the entire Gauss-Jordan elimination... This made me think I made a mistake somewhere, but I have gone over my calculations several times and I can't seem to find any mistakes. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: You could use `&` for typing the matrix. Also, using `pmatrix` instead of `matrix` would give you the proper parentheses.

Comment: The determinant of the original matrix is $3(23(-2)-(-3)39)-11(7(-2)-(-4)39)+19(7(-3)-(-4)23) = 3124$. So the system is not inconsistent. You made a mistake somewhere (or I did - but I don't have time right now to make sure I got the signs right).

Comment: All looks fine to me.